# How can I perform this replacement?

Tags: replacement

I want to take an expression of the form

```
p[1,2]p[3,4]
```

and have an output of something like

```
{{1,2},{3,4}}
```

If I do the replacement

```
p[i_,j_]:>{i,j}
```

this ends up multiplying the two lists together, which I don't want. How can I do this? It also needs to be for an arbitrary number of `p[i,j]`

Comment: `p[1, 2] p[3, 4] /. {Times | p -> List}`

Comment: List @@@ List @@ (p[1, 2] p[3, 4])